# googlemap sdk having issue with the ios architecture

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

As the apple map adk is not well detailed on street details, and the google has provided the new sdk, I am trying to get this as a work around for the current ios 6, the problem that I am facing is that it is throwing error no matter what architecture you have placed in the settings,
Following is the error, though it works with no problem when running there sdkmapdemo :(

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "___gxx_personality_sj0", referenced from:
      +[GMSServices provideAPIKey:] in GoogleMaps(GMSServices.o)
      +[GMSServices openSourceLicenseInfo] in GoogleMaps(GMSServices.o)
      +[GMSServices services] in GoogleMaps(GMSServices.o)
      _GMS_NSClassFromString in GoogleMaps(GMSRenames.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you add `libstdc++.dylib` to the project's frameworks?

Comment: still getting ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/arjunchaudhary/Documents/xcode/School Bus New_new/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You need to change the architectures to just armv7 (the SDK doesn't support armv7s).

Comment: See the first part of step 7 under https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project